# how to merge multiple select in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, join, subquery

i have severals tables, named like these:

```
table_2012_12
table_2012_10
table_2012_07
```

both with the same structure:

```
id
order_id
account_id
```

i know i have to perform these queries:

```
SELECT * FROM table_2012_12 where id=1
SELECT * FROM table_2012_12 where id=5  
SELECT * FROM table_2012_10 where id=1
SELECT * FROM table_2012_07 where id=22
```

What's the best (in performances) method to use a single query?

Comment: After you've taken one of the union queries below, use them to construct a single new table called 'all_time_table' with a date field in it.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UNION` operator does that. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html

```
SELECT * FROM table_2012_12 where id=1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table_2012_12 where id=5  
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table_2012_10 where id=1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table_2012_07 where id=22
```

Usually, you should not just write `UNION` but `UNION ALL`. `UNION` has the effect of joining the query results, as well as filtering out any duplicate rows. `UNION ALL` will simply merge the query results, and keep all rows. This is much more efficient

Answer (score 1):

Given this structure, you can't do any optimization but you may make a [union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) query :

```
SELECT * FROM table_2012_12 where id=1
UNION SELECT * FROM table_2012_12 where id=5  
UNION SELECT * FROM table_2012_10 where id=1
UNION SELECT * FROM table_2012_07 where id=22
```

`UNION` will automatically remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table_2012_12 where id=1 OR  id=5
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table_2012_10 where id=1
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table_2012_07 where id=22
```